# Differential Equation : $\frac{dy}{dx} +\int_0^5{y\,dx}=27$

Tags: probability, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

Given $y=f(x)$ , is twice differentiable, passes through the origin and satisfies the equation, $$\frac{dy}{dx} +\int_0^5{y\,dx}=27$$What is the probability that $2$ randomly chosen variables $a$, $b$ from the set $S=\{1,2,3,4\}$ lies on the curve as $(a,b)$?

**My Attempt:**

As $\int_0^5{y\,dx}$ is a constant.

$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=0$$

Therefore, $y=ax+b$,

As curve passes through the origin, $b=0$, so $y=ax$.

On putting this in the equation, we get $a=2$.

Therefore, $$y=2x.$$

> **Is my approach right? And also how else can we attempt this question?**

Comment: Why this question has a tag "Probability"?

Comment: Seems flne, so far. Now you have to work out which values $(a,b)$ chosen from $S$ lie on the curve.

Comment: @JaideepKhare What is the probability that $2$ randomly chosen variables $a$ ,$b$ from the set $S={1,2,3,4}$ lies on the curve as $(a,b)$?

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan Oh, Sorry! I didn't read that line.

Comment: nitpick: What suggests $f$ is twice differentiable?

Comment: @qbert, question stated that. I forgot to add it here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have $y=2x$ so the only integer combinations from your set $S$ are $(1, 2)$ and $(2, 4)$.

The probability is thus $\dfrac2{4\cdot4}=\dfrac18$.